# Copy file recursively with a json file to give condition over folder

Tags: powershell, copy

**What i'm looking for ?**

I'm trying to copy file recursively with Powershell. The problem is that, i use this command to detect file with date:

```
$dir = "C:\Folder"
$Latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} 
echo $Latest
```

Now i need to things:

**Copy files**

I need to copy only files that verify this date condition.

**Set different condition over folders**

I would like to set different conditions over subfolders.
For example, i would like to set the AddDays condition to -7 for `Subfolder1` and to -30 to `Subfolder2`

Have you guys any idea about this ? I saw somewhere that we can set it with a Json file but I didn't find how to do it.

**Edit**

I'm now trying to add something like `| ForEach-Object {copy-item $_ $to}` but i'm getting errors. Do you know how can i deal with it ?

Comment: Do different runs on Subfolder1 and Subfolder2.

Comment: Yes but the thing is that in my example i have 2 subfolders but in reality i have about 50 subfolders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might do

```
$addDays = @{Subfolder1 =-7; Subfolder2=-30}
$dir = "C:\Folder"
$Latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays($addDays[$_.Name])} 
echo $Latest
```

The gist of this is to create a hasharray that can be used in your where clause to substitute the items name with the number of days to add

**Edit**

taking into account your comments, the selection of the array item gets more convoluted but could be done as follows

```
$addDays = @{Subfolder1 =-7; Subfolder2=-30}
$dir = "C:\Folder\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -File | 
  where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays($addDays[$_.DirectoryName -replace [Regex]::Escape($dir) -replace "\\.*$"])}
```

Comment: I suspect the OP wants the filters for the files in those subfolders, so a simple selector like this wouldn't suffice.

Comment: I'm gonna try this

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - perhaps but in that case OP should at least add the `recursive` parameter (or another gci).

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers i added the -Recurse, but when i do `echo $Latest` nothing happens. I suspect that there is "maybe" something wrong

Comment: @OrhanYazar - I have edited the answer to what I currently think you mean :)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I tried your edited post and `echo $Latest`  retunr nothing. But this time, it took a litle bit longer, it seems that he did something. Of course i defined `$Latest` just before.

Comment: You can try following script to debug the issue but for me, it works?! (note the trailing slash for $dir!)
`Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -File | % {$_.FullName;$_.LastWriteTime;(Get-Date).AddDays($addDays[$_.DirectoryName -replace [Regex]::Escape($dir) -replace "\\.*$"])}`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Sorry my friend i just forgot to write \ at the end of the dir. But is it possible to take a Json file in $addDays instead of writing it in the shell code ?

Comment: I should have been more explicit. As for you json question, yes its possible but not my cup of tea. You'r better of posting a new question for that.